# How do I check contract deployment status?

Tags: contract-deployment

If I send the transaction to create a contract and don't want to wait around for it to be deployed, how can I later check to see if it's deployed, given that the contract address is provided only once it has been fully deployed? Is there another 'ID' that is returned straight away that I can use to later query the blockchain to see if the contract has been deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> given that the contract address is provided only once it has been fully deployed

False. Contract address is deterministic and can be calculated ahead of time of deployment.

- You can check if an address has code payload using EXTCODESIZE
- You can check the success status/[revert reason](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/_autosummary/eth_defi.revert_reason.fetch_transaction_revert_reason.html#eth_defi.revert_reason.fetch_transaction_revert_reason) of the deployment transaction from its transaction receipt. The receipt you get over JSON-RPC using the transaction hash.

Answer (score 1):

Well you usually get for example in ethereum an etherscan link that shows the status of the transaction (Contract deployment).

To my knowlegde there's no actual other id besides contract address, Only the etherscan link, with the status, block number etc..